# While retrieve a model by ID from a Backbone.js collection returning undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to get a model from a collection by it's ID and display in view. After instantiating a model, I'm using the methods like `get()`, `at()` but it's returning `undefined`.

My collection:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "firstname": "Abc",
        "lastname": "Xyz"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "firstname": "Klm",
        "lastname": "Opq"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "firstname": "rst",
        "lastname": "Yvw"
    }
]
```

Instantiation:

`var persons = new PersonCollection();`

`console.log(persons.get(1)); // undefined`

NOTE: I'm getting all the models in console (Not an issue). I want only to fetch a model by it's id name.

Comment: How do you populate `persons`? In your example it is empty.

Comment: var PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model: PersonModel,
 url: "http://localhost/socialapp/php/fetch.php"
});

var persons = new PersonCollection();

persons.fetch();

console.log(persons.get(1));  // undefined

Comment: @LipakSahil Please [edit]  question and add information there. don't put code blocks in comments where it's unreadable

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` is async so you need to place your code inside success callback

```
persons.fetch({
  success: function() {
     console.log('Now I have something: ', persons.get(1))
  }
})

console.log('Nothing here: ', persons.get(1))
```

BTW to fetch single model by id you could use [`Model#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) instead

Comment: still i'm getting undefined.

Comment: Check your server response and log `persons.toJSON()` **inside** the callback.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to get the model by ID. My router URL is like this: http://localhost/socialapp/#/person_list/12.  --> "12" is id value. I have setup my application in MVC structure. (model, view, collections). Hence no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting all the objects in an Array in the console. Till this its working fine.. But i need the above router URL should fetch the model by ID.

Comment: You could use [Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) to achive this. Inside route handler you get the id, fetch model by id and render corresponding view. But this should be a separate question I guess.

Comment: @LipakSahil If the information you've provided is correct, then this answer will work. If it's not working you've provided wrong info. Please create a [mcve] with your code and sample response from backend.